# Auth0/angular-jwt - Not redirecting to login page when token has expired

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am using the latest version of Auth0/angular-jwt with my Angular app. I am testing my app when the token has expired on the client side and it tries to send the form to the server. The server returns an error status 401 because the token has expired and on the client side I am catching this 401 error and redirect the user to the login page but for some reason it is not redirecting the user to login page. What am I missing!!.Below are my code the component and service classes.

***component class code***

```
onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {

      this.coreService.createNewJob(this.form.value).pipe(
        tap((response) => console.log('tap response: ',response))
        )
        .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.form.reset();
          this.router.navigate(['/print']);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('Something went wrong : the Job wasn\'t saved.', error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

***service class code***

```
createNewJob(payload:IJob): Observable<IJob>{
       console.log('Payload being sent to server for new Job: ',payload.productGTIN);

       return this.httpClient.post<IJob>(environment.restUrl+'/newjob',payload)
       .pipe(
           tap(data => console.log('All: ', JSON.stringify(data))),
           catchError(this.handleError)
         );    
   }
 
 
 private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<never> {
       let errorMessage = '';
       if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
         // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
         errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
       } else {
         // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
         // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
         errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;

         if(err.status == 401)
         {
           console.error('Inside 401 error so redirect to login page ',errorMessage);
           this.router.navigate(['/session/login']);
           
         }
       }
       console.error('inside core handleerror() ');
       return throwError(errorMessage);
     }
```

***Screenshot of the browser console when I submit the form***

[image: console]

Comment: You aren't catching the error inside the service, but you are catching it in your component. In your screenshot I can't see any log about the service, so I deduce the error was throws by the navigation

Comment: Router has to be injected as dependency in service class.

Comment: @Shifenis -  In the screenshot the error is being thrown by core.service.ts which is my service class